# Is Stellar platform a blockchain?

Tags: consensus, ripple

I heard Stellar is a Ripple fork, is that right?
Since Ripple does not uses a blockchain, does Stellar use a blockchain?

Comment: Stellar isn't a ripple fork, though a first generation of the system was.  Moreover, Ripple does use a blockchain.  Two ripple blocks will not be identical unless they share identical histories.  Even minimal amounts of googling would have answered these questions, so if this isn't a troll (which seems like a distinct possibility), please check out the basics from the Stellar and Ripple web pages.

Comment: @user3188445 I'm not a troll, I'm just learning, and it's not clear that information, (I really was reading the docs). Thanks

Comment: Then my answer here might be of interest, since it discusses how the Stellar ledger headers form a chain: 
 https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/1310/difference-between-stellar-ledger-and-blocks/1312#1312

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my recent [blog post](https://www.lumenauts.com/blog/dark-archeology-digging-through-stellar-xdr-archives):

> Everybody knows that Stellar Network is a blockchain-powered platform, right? However, it's architecture is completely distinctive from, let's say, Bitcoin or Ethereum. There is no mining, no PoW or PoS algorithms, it resembles rather a database with a simplified API than Bitcoin sequence of blocks. So why is it listed on the CoinMarketCap with other "classic" blockchains? Because Stellar is an immutable distributed ledger.
>
> Immutability is one of the key blockchain concepts. All blocks in the ledger are sequential, and each new block is bound to its predecessor. Nobody can modify a block somewhere in the middle of the chain and enjoy one more million on the account balance because the whole chain becomes invalid. So we can safely assume that data on the blockchain is legitimate, having been verified by multiple network validators.

[Here](https://www.stellar.org/how-it-works/stellar-basics/explainers/) is a collection of short explainers that describe how everything works. And [advanced guide](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/ledger.html) for developers, which describes the concept of chained ledgers in details.

P.S. Stellar is not just a fork of Ripple (like LTC<>BTC). It shares with Ripple some ideological concepts, however Stellar has its own way, and the codebase is written from the scratch.